# How to avoid duplicating logic in react data table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable

I'm looking for help with structuring an entity data table component in react.

I'm using react-virtualized and am trying to determine how to encapsulate the boilerplate functionality used for server-side sorting/filtering/paging/row deletion/etc.

I started out with a simple, self-contained component which only required an API path, and handled everything by itself with local state.

Needing to be able to update/delete/add/refresh records from outside the table component, I moved the table state/logic into a container component that manages the table, along with some buttons and modal windows.

However, now that all the handlers for sorting/filtering/paging are in this container, it seems they would all have to be duplicated in order to be reused for other tables with slightly different requirements, but the exact same sorting/filtering/paging.

How can I contain the boilerplate table logic within the table component, while also being able to update/delete/add/refresh records from outside the component?

To visualize this, here is a contrived example where all the logic and state is encapsulated in the TableWithFilter component:

```
<SomeEntityList>
    <TableWithFilter apiPath={this.props.apiPath}>
        <FilterBar />
        <Table /> 
    <TableWithFilter>
</SomeEntityList>
```

the filter method and state could live in TableWithFilter:

```
TableWithFilter._handleFilter() {
    // get filter, inject filter into api path, get records, update state 
}
```

Now, lets say we need to add a modal so that we can edit the values in a row:

```
<SomeEntityList>
    <EditRowModal />
    <TableWithFilter>
        <FilterBar />
        <Table />
    <TableWithFilter>
</SomeEntityList>
```

The state and filter method then have to be moved up to the SomeEntityList component so that the modal can change the records in the table:

```
SomeEntityList._handleFilter() { 
    //get filter, inject filter into api path, get records, update state 
}

SomeEntityList._editRow() { 
    // make update call, update state 
}
```

Assuming I'll have dozens of various SomeEntityListA/SomeEntityListB/SomeEntityListC with various difference (some have edit record modals, some have buttons to add new records, etc) how would I avoid duplicating the filtering logic in dozens of places?

Comment: Wait why don't you just pass the filter as a param to `<TableWithFilter />` or whichever element is actually using the filter?'

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have two options.

- If the logic for the reusable filters are functional, you could probably move them out of the components entirely and put them in a `utils` directory or something.
- Use [higher-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

### Edit

Why don't you just pass the filter as a param?

Comment: This seems like a good place for a HOC, but I'm not sure what that would look like. The HOC could theoretically handle the sorting/filtering/paging logic, but not sure how an outside component could interact with the table, e.g. removing/adding/editing a record.
Any specific ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some time, I decided to circle back to this to help anyone else out.

I've since moved to incorporation redux in the project (for many reasons).
On this topic specifically, I now have a CreateSearchableTable function that acts a factory for creating namespaced SearchableTable reducers. This allows the reuse of all the fetching/infinite scrolling/paging/filtering/sorting logic. I'm currently working on finding the best way to remove duplicated action creators.